# Search page doesn't recognise post_type=page

Tags: pages, search

I've created some custom filter buttons for my search page, listing various custom post_types. Included in the list is the basic 'page' `post_type`. However, when I use this filter (updating the url to `/?s=test&post_type=page` for e.g.) this doesn't seem to be included in the default `WP_Query` being run on the page.

If I `print_r($wp_query)` I can see every other `post_type` being mirrored in the query. However when `post_type=page` is passed, the query doesn't pick it up.

Is this usual behavior? If so, how can I make the search page only return pages, not posts?

Comment: are you creating a brand new query to customize what's on the search pages template based on your filters via`get_posts`/`query_posts`/`WP_Query`? Or making modifications to the `$wp_query` object? Note that `s=post_type=page` isn't a valid URL get parameter as `s` is missing a value and there is no `&` to indicate a second URL parameter

Comment: @TomJNowell edited. The URL being passes is actually `/?s=test&post_type=page`. I'm not creating a new search query, just trying to patch into the existing one. Passing any other post_type in the URL works, I can't work out why `page` doesn't.

Comment: do you have `pre_get_posts` filters in your codebase?

Comment: @TomJNowell no, I don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63678063/wordpress-search-filtering-pages-and-posts

I customised the function as follows:

```
function page_search_filter( \WP_Query $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
            if ( isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page' ) {
                $query->set( 'post_type','page' );
            }
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'page_search_filter' );
```